# Return the column of a cell using hlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to return the column of a cell using something like hlookup.

So if I were to look for "product model" I would get G

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you'd want to use `G` somewhere else. Is this related to your previous question? Did that not show you a good way using `XLOOKUP()`?

Comment: Speaking of former questions... You have a whole bunch of them open but answered. Please revisit these questions and see if these indeed are answered and ready to close (checkmark next to answers).

Comment: The solution you provided to the last question was very complex

Comment: What is complex about it? You should provide feedback over there instead of opening new questions to ask the same thing to be honest.